# Print Lines from .csv based off criteria inputted from user

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and am looking for guidance on the task I am working on.

I am importing a csv file that looks like the list below.

```
invoice_id,customer_first_name,customer_last_name,part_number,quantity,total

18031,Hank,Scorpio,367,1,2.63
54886,Max,Power,171,3,50.79
19714,Jonathan,Frink,179,2,7.93
19714,Jonathan,Frink,378,2,32.34
22268,Gil,Gunderson,165,2,47.15
87681,Lionel,Hutz,218,1,50.83
84508,Lurleen,Lumpkin,257,1,81.95
34018,Lionel,Hutz,112,3,88.88
34018,Lionel,Hutz,386,3,86.04
34018,Lionel,Hutz,216,1,53.54
66648,Patty,Bouvier,203,3,70.47
```

I only want to print each line if its based off the criteria inputted by the user. For example, if the user inputs lname and then inputs Hutz the following would be printed out.

```
87681,Lionel,Hutz,218,1,50.83
34018,Lionel,Hutz,112,3,88.88
34018,Lionel,Hutz,386,3,86.04
34018,Lionel,Hutz,216,1,53.54
4 records found.
```

This is what I have so far...

```
salesdatafile= None
while True:
    salesdatafilename=input("Enter the name of the file:")
    try:
        salesdata= open(salesdatafilename, 'r')
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("{0} was not found".format ( salesdatafilename ))

search=input("Do you want to search by invoice id or lname? Please type id or lname: ")
idsearch=salesdata.readline() 

if search== 'id':
    idnumber=print(int(input('Please enter Id to search: ')))
    while idsearch != '':
        if idsearch== idnumber:
            print(idsearch)

else:
    lname=print(input('Please enter your last name: '))
    while idsearch != '':
        if idsearch== lname:
            print(idsearch)
```

All that is printing out is lname or id inputted by the user.

Comment: `looking for guidance on the task`. This is commendable, but SO may not be the best place for general guidance. Do you have a **specific** question? What I mean: is there a specific line or part of your code which is not behaving the way you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a csv module built in that you should be utilizing. Check out the below example code:

```
import csv
salesdatafilename = r"path/to/file.txt"
data = csv.reader(open(salesdatafilename))
last_name_to_look_for = "Lionel"
for invoice_id, customer_first_name, customer_last_name, part_number, quantity, total in data:
     if customer_last_name == last_name_to_look_for:
        print(invoice_id, customer_first_name, customer_last_name, part_number, quantity, total)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are comparing the entire line to the idnumber or lname. Instead you might want to try something like

```
if lname in idsearch:
    <do something>
```

this will check if the lname is in the line somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For performance, I will use a generator to read the lines so that my program doesn’t crash were this to be a bigger file. So I will yield each line in that file with a generator function. Since generators return iteratirs, I will then iterate and filter every line that does not contain my search value and return only those that contain my search value.