# read data table from .txt file and parse it to variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to read data table from .txt file with python 2.7, and parse it to variable sir...
I hope someone help me..

I have data on .txt (10 item):

```
LEW01,14/01/2016,07:50:00,15.6,-19,943,-8.7,-228,-19,943,-8.7,-0.9,48.5,4.14,12.39
LEW01,14/01/2016,08:00:00,16.2,-18,944,-8.6,-229,-19,943,-8.6,-0.9,48.5,4.14,12.39
LEW01,14/01/2016,08:10:00,16.8,-19,943,-8.7,-228,-18,944,-8.6,-0.9,48.4,4.16,12.39
LEW01,14/01/2016,08:20:00,17.6,-18,944,-8.6,-229,-18,943,-8.6,-0.9,48.5,4.16,12.44
LEW01,14/01/2016,08:30:00,18.4,-19,943,-8.6,-229,-18,943,-8.6,-0.9,48.5,0.96,12.44
LEW01,14/01/2016,08:40:00,19.4,-18,944,-8.6,-230,-18,943,-8.6,-0.9,48.4,4.18,12.49
LEW01,14/01/2016,08:50:00,20.8,-19,943,-8.7,-230,-18,943,-8.6,-0.9,48.6,4.18,12.49
LEW01,14/01/2016,09:00:00,22.2,-18,944,-8.6,-231,-18,942,-8.6,-0.9,48.6,4.18,12.49
LEW01,14/01/2016,09:10:00,23.4,-19,943,-8.7,-232,-17,942,-8.6,-0.9,48.6,4.18,12.54
LEW01,14/01/2016,09:20:00,24.6,-18,944,-8.6,-233,-17,942,-8.6,-0.9,48.7,4.18,12.59
```

when i compile with code python:

```
with open('data_peng.txt') as x:
    for rec in x:
        a=rec.split(',')[0]
        b=rec.split(',')[1]
        c=rec.split(',')[2]
        d=rec.split(',')[3]
        e=rec.split(',')[4]
        f=rec.split(',')[5]
        g=rec.split(',')[6]
        h=rec.split(',')[7]
        i=rec.split(',')[8]
        j=rec.split(',')[9]
        k=rec.split(',')[10]
        l=rec.split(',')[11]
        m=rec.split(',')[12]
        n=rec.split(',')[13]
        o=rec.split(',')[14]
```

*output :*

```
>>> a
'LEW01'
>>> b
'14/01/2016'
>>> c
'09:20:00'
>>> d
'24.6'
>>> e
'-18'
>>> f
'944'
>>> g
'-8.6'
>>> h
'-233'
>>> i
'-17'
>>> j
'942'
>>> k
'-8.6'
>>> l
'-0.9'
>>> m
'48.7'
>>> n
'4.18'
>>> o
'12.59'
```

That I want , for example variable c:

```
>>> c
 [07:50:00,08:00:00,08:10:00,08:20:00,08:30:00,08:40:00,08:50:00,09:00:00,09:10:00,09:20:00]
```

Please help me, thanks a lot

Comment: Use the csv module that comes built in to python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662220/print-lines-from-csv-based-off-criteria-inputted-from-user/50662332#50662332

Comment: thanks a lot sir eyllanesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution that will populate a single object with the column names you're looking for:

```
import csv

o = {}
cols = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']
with open('data_peng.txt', 'r') as csvin:
   csvin = csv.reader(csvin)
   for row in csvin:
       for idx, col in enumerate(cols):
           o.setdefault(col, []).append(row[idx])

print o['c']
```

Comment: I have some problem in : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/read_col2.py", line 4, in <module>
    csvin = csv.reader(csvin)
NameError: name 'csv' is not defined............... but solved when we input : import csv

Comment: Thank you for your give me solution , sir.

Comment: the main purpose is how the data can be inserted into a formula, such as FFT (fast fourier transform), where the result will be appended to the last column in each row. Can you help me, How do I get in every line, have my own FFT results? Do we need to make a loop? Or put the data contained in col3 into a new variable to be retrieved into a formula like FFT? Sir ic3b3rg or someone else?

Comment: please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673965/get-data-form-lines-rows-to-input-on-new-column-in-the-last-rows-lines

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
with open('data_peng.txt') as x:
    col3 = [line.split(',')[2] for line in x]

print(col3)
```

That being said, it looks like a CSV, and any more sophisticated parsing might benefit from the use of python's builtin [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html).

Also, I edited your question's formatting, please make sure I didn't change anything important.

Comment: the main purpose is how the data can be inserted into a formula, such as FFT (fast fourier transform), where the result will be appended to the last column in each row. Can you help me, How do I get in every line, have my own FFT results?

Comment: Do we need to make a loop? Or put the data contained in col3 into a new variable to be retrieved into a formula like FFT? Sir jedwards, sir ic3b3rg or someone else?

Comment: please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673965/get-data-form-lines-rows-to-input-on-new-column-in-the-last-rows-lines